# Broadcasting to a array variable in node

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
for (var key in rows) {

    var userid = rows[key].user_id;

    listsusers.push(userid);
}

console.log(listsusers);
```

shows output [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] in terminal

I need to broadcast it to corresponding users 1,2,3,4 with their user id's.

I tried this to broadcast:

```
socket.broadcast.to(listsusers).emit('user_count', {
    'user_id': userid
});
```

Comment: Do you have any more information you could provide?

Comment: what type info i should share?

Comment: I was trying with broadcasting to all user Ids in array variable listusers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting the  broadcast statement inside the loop

```
   for (var key in rows) {

    var userid = rows[key].user_id;

    socket.broadcast.to(userid).emit('user_count', {'user_id': userid}

    });

    console.log(listsusers);
```